# How can I get the image value in Json by using Javascript

Tags: json

```
{  
   "\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe":{  
       "server":"ia601507.us.archive.org",
       "dir":"\/33\/items\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe",
       "misc":{  
          "image":"https:\/\/ia601507.us.archive.org\/33\/items\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe.thumbs\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe_000001.jpg",
          "collection-title":"Denver Open Media"
       }
   }
}
```

This is my Json file, how can I get the image value by using JS? 
"/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe" will not always same
Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. Removing the redundant tag JSON leaves *Basic questions*, which has absolutely no indication of what you're asking. Your title should describe a problem or question in a way that will convey meaning to future readers here seeing it in a list of search results. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Edited for your requirement of changing field name.

```
for (var k in obj) {
   var image = obj[k].misc.image;
}
```

Where `obj` is your JSON object.

### Proof

```js
function mySolution(obj) {
  for (var k in obj) {
    var image = obj[k].misc.image;
    console.log(image);
  }
}

var obj = {  
   "\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe":{  
       "server":"ia601507.us.archive.org",
       "dir":"\/33\/items\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe",
       "misc":{  
          "image":"https:\/\/ia601507.us.archive.org\/33\/items\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe.thumbs\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe_000001.jpg",
          "collection-title":"Denver Open Media"
       }
   }
}

mySolution(obj);

obj = {  
   "\/dom-sdasdfasdfasdfasdf-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe":{  
       "server":"ia601507.us.archive.org",
       "dir":"\/33\/items\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe",
       "misc":{  
          "image":"https:\/\/ia601507.us.archive.org\/33\/items\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe.thumbs\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe_000001.jpg",
          "collection-title":"Denver Open Media"
       }
   }
}

mySolution(obj);
```

Comment: I have many images, and  \/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe will change on every image.

Comment: @JiangZhan Updated my solution. Sorry about missing the requirement initially.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't know what the key is going to be, you need to loop over the JSON for each key. Then you can output the image based with `json[key].misc.image`, as `image` is inside of `misc`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var json = {  
   "\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe":{  
       "server":"ia601507.us.archive.org",
       "dir":"\/33\/items\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe",
       "misc":{  
          "image":"https:\/\/ia601507.us.archive.org\/33\/items\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe.thumbs\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe_000001.jpg",
          "collection-title":"Denver Open Media"
       }
   },
   "another_key":{  
       "server":"ia601507.us.archive.org",
       "dir":"\/33\/items\/dom-12239-1-cover-band-2018-greg-goodloe",
       "misc":{  
          "image":"another_image",
          "collection-title":"Denver Open Media"
       }
   }
};

for(var key in json) {
  console.log(json[key].misc.image);
}
```

Hope this helps! :)